# How do I replace -0.0 values with 0.0 values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

About a ~week ago I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67908246/how-to-group-the-cumulative-sum-of-rain-values-into-a-new-column-for-given-times) where I used the `rolling().sum().round()` method to create new columns and add to the data frame. However, I have some values in the data frame as `-0.0` but I want to replace it with `0.0`.

Here's an example:

`print(assomption_rain_df.head(25))`

```
          date      time  rain_gauge_value        
0   2020-08-05  00:00:00               5.3                  
1   2020-08-05  01:00:00               2.7                  
2   2020-08-05  02:00:00               2.2                  
3   2020-08-05  03:00:00               3.0                  
4   2020-08-05  04:00:00               1.5     
5   2020-08-05  05:00:00               0.0     
6   2020-08-05  06:00:00               0.0     
7   2020-08-05  07:00:00               0.0     
8   2020-08-05  08:00:00               0.1     
9   2020-08-05  09:00:00               0.1     
10  2020-08-05  10:00:00               0.1     
11  2020-08-05  11:00:00               0.4     
12  2020-08-05  12:00:00               0.5     
13  2020-08-05  13:00:00               0.2     
14  2020-08-05  14:00:00               0.3     
15  2020-08-05  15:00:00               0.4     
16  2020-08-05  16:00:00               0.2     
17  2020-08-05  17:00:00               0.0     
18  2020-08-05  18:00:00               0.0    
19  2020-08-05  19:00:00               0.0     
20  2020-08-05  20:00:00               0.0     
21  2020-08-05  21:00:00               0.0     
22  2020-08-05  22:00:00               0.0     
23  2020-08-05  23:00:00               0.0    
24  2020-08-06  00:00:00               0.0
```

`assomption_rain_df['rain_gauge_value_6hr']=assomption_rain_df['rain_gauge_value'].rolling(6).sum().round(1)`

`print(assomption_rain_df.head(25))`

```
          date      time  rain_gauge_value rain_gauge_value_6hr       
0   2020-08-05  00:00:00               5.3                  NaN
1   2020-08-05  01:00:00               2.7                  NaN
2   2020-08-05  02:00:00               2.2                  NaN
3   2020-08-05  03:00:00               3.0                  NaN
4   2020-08-05  04:00:00               1.5                  NaN
5   2020-08-05  05:00:00               0.0                 14.7
6   2020-08-05  06:00:00               0.0                  9.4
7   2020-08-05  07:00:00               0.0                  6.7
8   2020-08-05  08:00:00               0.1                  4.6
9   2020-08-05  09:00:00               0.1                  1.7
10  2020-08-05  10:00:00               0.1                  0.3
11  2020-08-05  11:00:00               0.4                  0.7
12  2020-08-05  12:00:00               0.5                  1.2
13  2020-08-05  13:00:00               0.2                  1.4
14  2020-08-05  14:00:00               0.3                  1.6   
15  2020-08-05  15:00:00               0.4                  1.9
16  2020-08-05  16:00:00               0.2                  2.0
17  2020-08-05  17:00:00               0.0                  1.6
18  2020-08-05  18:00:00               0.0                  1.1
19  2020-08-05  19:00:00               0.0                  0.9
20  2020-08-05  20:00:00               0.0                  0.6
21  2020-08-05  21:00:00               0.0                  0.2
22  2020-08-05  22:00:00               0.0                 -0.0
23  2020-08-05  23:00:00               0.0                 -0.0
24  2020-08-06  00:00:00               0.0                 -0.0
```

How do I replace `-0.0` values with `0.0` values in a data frame?

UPDATE: Thank you for your help! Adding `.abs()` after `.round(1)` solved the problem.

Comment: How do you replace *anything* is a dataframe?

Comment: Your code as given `assomption_rain_df['rain_gauge_value'].rolling(6).sum().round(1)` does not reproduce the issue. The values at index 22 - 24 show as 0.0. Please update pandas to the current version of 1.2.4. If you are using conda, at the conda prompt do `conda update --all`.

Comment: Incidentally, the issue is most likely attributable to floating point rounding. Since there should never be a negative value, you could also add `.abs()` after `.round()`

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace values, that are -0.0 with 0:

```
assomption_rain_df['rain_gauge_value_6hr'][assomption_rain_df['rain_gauge_value_6hr'] == -0.0] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`DataFrame.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```py
assomption_rain_df['rain_gauge_value_6hr'] = assomption_rain_df['rain_gauge_value_6hr'].replace(-0, 0)
```